# Inline expression to use in text attribute of asp.net control

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any inline expression to use in text attribute of an asp control? I have been using the texts from a resource file like this as below.

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="LtrLogin" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, Login_Heading %>" />
<asp:Button="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, Login_Text %>" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" OnClientClick="getHitDate()" />
```

For some reasons, I need to take texts from a C# method. I use the below expression for that.

```
<%= CustomResourceHandler.GetResourceValue("Login_Heading")%> //instead of asp:Literal element
<asp:Button="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="<%= CustomResourceHandler.GetResourceValue("Login_Text")%>" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" OnClientClick="getHitDate()" />//This doesn't work
```

But I can't use this inside the text attribute of the asp:Button element.
Is there any possible way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this syntax

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" Text='<%# CustomResourceHandler.GetResourceValue("Login_Text") %>' />
```

But in order for this to work you have to call DataBind in code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```